# Control variate for Heston model

Tags: monte-carlo

Does anyone have suggestions for potential control variates for vanillas in a Heston model? I've tried black scholes with implied volatility, average volatility and long term volatility all without great success, so I'm hoping you guys got an idea.

Comment: Are your vanillas American or European exercise?  What pricing algorithm are you using?

Comment: European. I've implemented Kaya-Broadie, full trunctuation and naive euler, but I'm willing to change if that makes it easier :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Glassermans's book suggests the **stock price** as the default idea for a control variate.
In this paper, ["Efficient, almost exact simulation of the Heston stochastic volatility model"](http://arno.uvt.nl/show.cgi?fid=92651), by Haastrecht and Pelsser, (2008) the authors claim that this approach also works well for the Heston model (see appendix A2).

The book is very approachable and available online: [Monte Carlo Methods in Financial Engineering](https://camjclub.wikispaces.com/file/view/Monte%20Carlo%20Methods%20In%20Financial%20Engineering.pdf/367817134/Monte%20Carlo%20Methods%20In%20Financial%20Engineering.pdf), Paul Glasserman, 2003.